# Are 'game theory' and 'economic theory' composite nominals or compound nouns?

Tags: nouns

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (Page 448) has this section distinguishing between composite nominals and compound nouns:
[image]

According to CGEL, there are five syntactic tests for distinguishing composite nominals from compound nouns, and composite nominals pass all those tests whereas compound nouns cannot pass any. One of such tests is coordination.

For example, *new cars* and *London colleges* are both composite nominals because they pass the coordination test as follows:

> [*new and used*] *cars*
>
> *various* [*London and Oxford*] *colleges*

But *ice-cream* and *custard-cream* are both compound nouns because they cannot pass the coordination test.

> *[*ice- and custard-*]*creams*

I don't quite understand why CGEL uses hyphens for *ice cream* and *custard cream*, but I wouldn't use a hyphen for either. In any case, having a hyphen has nothing to do with the distinction between composite nominals and compound nouns.

My question is whether 'game theory' and 'economic theory' are composite nominals or compound nouns.

I initially thought they were compound nouns, but there are some examples of them being used in coordination, as follows:

> [Robert Aumann’s Game and Economic Theory](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/hart/papers/aumann-n.pdf?)
>   (The title of an academic paper)
>
> [Mathematical Methods of Game and Economic Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/048646265X)
>   (The title of a book)

Is it correct to coordinate 'game theory' and 'economic theory' as in these examples?

If so, are they composite nominals and not compound nouns, as defined by CGEL?

Comment: I can find "blue and Steller's jay" on the internet as well, but I am absolutely sure that "blue jay" is a compound noun.

Comment: @PeterShor Do you find _game and economic theory_ wrong? And this phrase is not found on the Internet, but on a paper, book, etc.

Comment: Just because something appeared in a paper, does not mean that it is especially well-written. In fact, I suspect that papers in scientific and mathematical journals are much more likely to have been written by non-native speakers (who would not understand arcane grammatical rules that native English speakers intuit but are not taught in ESL classes) than random stuff on the Internet.

Comment: This is a pin dance.  The guys at Cambridge love to choreograph such performances, but they are of little practical benefit.

Comment: I'd write << game theory and economic theory >> but quite often << brown and black bears >>, << blue and Steller's jays >>, << blue and fin whales >> and << common and grey seals >>. All of these terms are accepted as compound nouns, but should be conceded (I've checked that I'm far from alone in my acceptability stances, and that the examples seem to be from respectable sources, eg the US National Library of Medicine National Institutes of Health, Alaska Department of Fish and Game) to pass the coordination test.

Comment: What difference would it make if these terms were classified one way or the other?  In the particular context of academic definition of types of theory there are very numerous examples in the form "X Y theory" that are not at all the same thing as "X theory and Y theory". It is far from certain that "Game and Economic Theory" is a reference to two theories or to one.

Comment: @JeremyC If you read the first few sentences of the cited paper and book, you'll know that _Game and Economic Theory_ refers to "Game Theory and Economic Theory".

Comment: @JK2 That might well be so in the particular case, but I was referring to the general case of  "<foo> and <bar> theory".